# N-TH root of number in C++

Tags: c++, mingw, pow

I'm trying to calculate the n-root of a number in c++ using pow, so I tried to do as follow

```
#include <cmath.h>
...
double n_root_of_a = pow(a,1.0/n);
...
```

but this isn't working it gives me the following execution error "Process returned -1073741571 (0xC00000FD)". but if I run the same code in an online compiler It's works fine.
I'm using Codeblocks with MINGW on windows and don't know what is happening.

EDIT:
full code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <vector>
#include <stack>
#include <cmath>
#include <cctype>

const char ADD = '+';
const char SUB = '-';
const char MUL = '*';
const char DIV = '/';
const char POW = '^';
const char ROOT = '~';

using namespace std;

template<typename elem>
ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const vector<elem>& vec)
{
    typename vector<elem>::const_iterator it = vec.begin();
    os << "{";
    while(it != vec.end())
    {
        os << *it;
        it++;
        if(it == vec.end())
            os << "}";
        else
            os << ", ";
    }
    return os;
}

double add(double op1, double op2)
{
    return op1 + op2;
}

double sub(double op1, double op2)
{
    return op1 - op2;
}

double mul(double op1, double op2)
{
    return op1 * op2;
}

double div(double op1, double op2)
{
    return op1 / op2;
}

double pow(double op1, double op2)
{
    return pow(op1,op2);
}

double root(double op1, double op2)
{
    cout << op1 << endl;
    cout << op2 << endl;
    cout << 1.0/op2 << endl;
    cout << pow(4.0,0.5) << endl;
    return pow(op1,1.0/op2);
}



bool calculate(vector<char> rpn, double& res)
{
    vector<char>::iterator it = rpn.begin();
    stack<double> operands;
    bool error = false;
    while(it != rpn.end() && !error)
    {
        cout << "while with it: " << *it << endl;
        switch(*it)
        {
        case ADD:
            {
            if(operands.size() < 2)
                error = true;
            double op2 = operands.top();
            operands.pop();
            double op1 = operands.top();
            operands.pop();
            res = add(op1,op2);
            cout << "add with op1: " << op1 << ", op2: " << op2 << " y res: " << res << endl;
            operands.push(res);
            break;
            }
        case SUB:
            {
            if(operands.size() < 2)
                error = true;
            double op2 = operands.top();
            operands.pop();
            double op1 = operands.top();
            operands.pop();
            res = sub(op1,op2);
            cout << "sub with op1: " << op1 << ", op2: " << op2 << " y res: " << res << endl;
            operands.push(res);
            break;
            }
        case MUL:
            {
            if(operands.size() < 2)
                error = true;
            double op2 = operands.top();
            operands.pop();
            double op1 = operands.top();
            operands.pop();
            res = mul(op1,op2);
            cout << "mul with op1: " << op1 << ", op2: " << op2 << " y res: " << res << endl;
            operands.push(res);
            break;
            }
        case DIV:
            {
            if(operands.size() < 2)
                error = true;
            double op2 = operands.top();
            operands.pop();
            double op1 = operands.top();
            operands.pop();
            res = div(op1,op2);
            cout << "div with op1: " << op1 << ", op2: " << op2 << " y res: " << res << endl;
            operands.push(res);
            break;
            }
        case POW:
            {
            if(operands.size() < 2)
                error = true;
            double op2 = operands.top();
            operands.pop();
            double op1 = operands.top();
            operands.pop();
            res = pow(op1,op2);
            cout << "pow with op1: " << op1 << ", op2: " << op2 << " y res: " << res << endl;
            operands.push(res);
            break;
            }
        case ROOT:
            {
            if(operands.size() < 2)
                error = true;
            double op2 = operands.top();
            operands.pop();
            double op1 = operands.top();
            operands.pop();
            res = root(op1,op2);
            cout << "root with op1: " << op1 << ", op2: " << op2 << " y res: " << res << endl;
            operands.push(res);
            break;
            }
        default:
            {
            cout << "entra al default" << endl;
            int op;
            if (isdigit(*it))
                op = (int) *it - '0';
            else
                op = (int) *it - 'a' + 10;
            operands.push(op);
            break;
            }
        }
        it++;
    }
    if(operands.size() == 1){
        res = operands.top();
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

char inttochar(int a) {
    if (a >= 0 && a <= 9)
        return '0' + a;
    else
        return 'a' + a - 10;
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    cout << "Hello world!" << endl;
    double xd = pow(4.0,0.5); // <-------------- here it's chrashes
    cout << xd << endl;
    vector<char> operators{ADD,SUB,MUL,DIV,POW,ROOT};
    vector<int> numbers(0);
    for(int i=1; i<argc; i++)
    {
        numbers.push_back(atoi(argv[i]));
    }
    cout << operators << endl;
    cout << numbers << endl;

    vector<char> rpn{'4','2',ROOT};
    double result = -20.0;
    if(calculate(rpn,result))
        cout << result << endl;

    vector<char> aux(0);
    /*for(int i=0; i<7; i++) {
        for()
    }*/
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Add full code to your question.

Comment: This single line seems correct to me, the bug must be elsewhere.

Comment: You probably have a stack overflow somewhere in your code. The `pow` line seems OK.

Comment: Please read [How do i ask a good question ?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Your code don't even compile.

Comment: `#include <cmath.h>` => `#include <cmath>` as a start.

Comment: As the exception means *Stack overflow*, I suspect that you are calling `pow` inside a (probably infinite) recursive function, and it could have crashed on another instruction. The error in this case is the infinite recursion.

Comment: @yvw I made a project with only that line and it works, now what I don't understand because it throws an error the other code.

Comment: @Mattii: As others already pointed out, you're probably running into an infinite recursion code path. You have to fix that. `pow` is probably innocent.

Comment: @Mattii "it thows an error in other code"... - you wrote that.

Comment: @AdrianMole Nothing change.

Comment: I just compiled on MSVC, and the compiler emitted a warning on the wrong line directly: warning C4717: 'pow' is recurrent on all paths, at line 54.

Comment: rename `pow` function to some other different name so that it doesn't clash with `std::pow`

Comment: You have a function defined as `double pow(double op1, double op2) {return pow(op1, op2);}`.     Your definition gives infinite recursion since it unconditionally calls itself, and does not call the standard `pow()`.

Comment: :facepalm: thats the error.

Comment: @Mattii: IMHO the bigger facepalm is, having all those operator definitions in the first place. What gives? It just makes the code harder to follow. And if you really need a visiting operator function, just use a lambda.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error is in your redefinition of `pow` at line 54, that calls itself:

```
double pow(double op1, double op2)
{
    return pow(op1,op2);
}
```

This is an infinite recursive function.
You can fix by calling `std::pow` in your overloaded function.
Or simply remove the overload completely, as it provides no value.